# Apply Feature Hashing to specific columns from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm a bit lost with the use of Feature Hashing in Python Pandas .

I have the a DataFrame with multiple columns, with many information in different types.  There is one column that represent a class for the data.

Example:

```
         col1   col2    colType
    1     1      2        'A'
    2     1      1        'B'
    3     2      4        'C'
```

My goal is to apply FeatureHashing for the ColType, in order to be able to apply a Machine Learning Algorithm.

I have created a separate DataFrame for the colType, having something like this:

```
                   colType  value
           1         'A'       1
           2         'B'       2
           3         'C'       3
           4         'D'       4
```

Then, applied Feature Hashing for this class Data Frame. But I don't understand how to add the result of Feature Hashing to my DataFrame with the info, in order to use it as an input in a Machine Learning Algorithm.

This is how I use FeatureHashing:

```
  from sklearn.feature_extraction import FeatureHasher
  fh = FeatureHasher(n_features=10, input_type='string')
  result = fh.fit_transform(categoriesDF)
```

How do I insert this FeatureHasher result, to my DataFrame? How bad is my approach? Is there any better way to achieve what I am doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer comes in late, but I stumbled upon the same problem and found this works:

```
fh = FeatureHasher(n_features=8, input_type='string')
sp = fh.fit_transform(df['colType'])
df = pd.DataFrame(sp.toarray(), columns=['fh1', 'fh2', 'fh3', 'fh4', 'fh5', 'fh6', 'fh7', 'fh8'])
pd.concat([df1, df], axis=1)
```

This creates a dataframe out of the sparse matrix retrieved by the FeatureHasher and concatenates the matrix to the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to One Hot Coding, using something like this:

```
categoriesDF = pd.get_dummies(categoriesDF)
```

This function will create a column for every non-category value, with 1 or 0.